# How does Play JPA EntityManager work?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am learning Play Framework, recently I tried to integrate JPA with Play, a simple CRUD was built, but I have a few questions.
Below are the steps we follow in JPA for some persistence operation.

```
1. Create EntityManager Factory.
2. Create EntityManager
3. Begining Transaction.
4. Persist data.
5. Commit Transaction.
6. Close EntityManager.
7. Close EntityManagerFactory
```

Consider the following code snippet

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Result getPersons() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = JPA.em().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);
    CriteriaQuery<User> all = cq.select(root);
    TypedQuery<User> allQuery = JPA.em().createQuery(all);
    JsonNode jsonNodes = toJson(allQuery.getResultList());
    return ok(jsonNodes);
}
```

As shown in the above code snippet, I have just used JPA.em() and nothing more.
My question is does this take care of all the above 7 steps, like getting connection from connectionFactory, begining Transaction, committing and closing connection etc.

Is it that simple, just JPA.em()? Please explain how this really works? Any more coding is required to close connections, so that it would not cross maximum connections configured in Data source for the reason being the connections were not closed appropriately as in the above code snippet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You specify more then `JPA.em()` in your example. You also use `@Transactional` annotation that specifies your transaction: with it you start the transaction and with the end of the block you commit the transaction. Additionally you config JPA in your app's `application.conf` and in `conf/META-INF/persistence.xml`. So, Play has everything it needs:

1. Create EntityManager Factory: Done by Play Framework during startup
2. Create EntityManager: Handled by Play framework
3. Begining Transaction: Handled via @Transactional annotation or by JPA.em().withTransaction
4. Persist data: Done via persist(myEntity) or merge(myEntity)
5. Commit Transaction: Handled via @Transactional annotation or by JPA.em().withTransaction
6. Close EntityManager: Handled by Play framework
7. Close EntityManagerFactory: Done by Play Framework during shutdown